# How to create transparent png image from bitmap?

Tags: image, delphi, bitmap, png, alpha-transparency

My task is:

1. Create a TBitmap object.
2. Fill it with transparent color (alpha = 0).
3. Assign this bitmap to TPngImage.
4. Save PNG file with alpha transparency.

How can I do it in Delphi XE?

```
var
  Png: TPngImage;
  X, Y: Integer;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create();
  Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  Png := TPngImage.Create();
  try
    Bitmap.SetSize(100, 100);

    // How to clear background in transparent color correctly?
    // I tried to use this, but the image in PNG file has solid white background:
    for Y := 0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
      for X := 0 to Bitmap.Width - 1 do
        Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y]:= $00FFFFFF;

    // Now drawing something on a Bitmap.Canvas...
    Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Rectangle(20, 20, 60, 60);

    // Is this correct?
    Png.Assign(Bitmap);
    Png.SaveToFile('image.png');
  finally
    Png.Free();
    Bitmap.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Just one sidenote, don't use `TCanvas.Pixels`, it's terribly slow and evil ;-) Use `TBitmap.Scanline` instead.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6950006/576719) to the question [How to save a png file with transparency?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6949094/576719) for an example.

Comment: Another sidenote, do you even need a bitmap ? Don't you want to render what you need directly on a PNG image canvas ?

Comment: @LURD Thanks, now I understand how to fill with transparent color: by settings `Bitmap.TransparentColor` and `Bitmap.Transparent` after filling background. Can you add this as answer please?

Comment: @TLama When I tried to do that, I got error "Canvas does not allow drawing"

Comment: @Andrew, you need to instantiate the `TPNGImage` by using `CreateBlank` not by `Create` to make its canvas drawable.

Comment: @TLama Great, didn't even know about this constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More or less a copy of [Dorin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6950006/576719).
It shows how to make a transparent png image and how to clear the background.

```
uses
  PngImage;
...

var
  bmp: TBitmap;
  png: TPngImage;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  bmp.SetSize(200,200);

  bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  bmp.Canvas.Rectangle( 20, 20, 160, 160 );

  bmp.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  bmp.Canvas.Rectangle(1, 1, 199, 199);

  bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  bmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  bmp.Canvas.TextOut( 35, 20, 'Hello transparent world');

  bmp.TransparentColor := clWhite;
  bmp.Transparent := True;

  png := TPngImage.Create;
  png.Assign( bmp );
  png.SaveToFile( 'C:\test.png' );

  bmp.Free;
  png.Free;
end;
```